# Files not being released, even with .Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, using

I have a simple C# application for renaming and resizing images, and I have a little problem - when it completes working with all given files, the last one always stays in the memory, or whatever, of the program, and I can't delete it without closing the program.

How can I make my code always release the files it works with after it has finished?

here's what I have

```
     private void processFiles() {
        foreach (string oldFileNamePath in fileEntries) {
            ...
            File.Move(oldFileNamePath, newFileNamePath);
            if (isResizeImage) {
                if (!extension.Equals(".gif")) {
                    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(newFileNamePath);
                    int newWidth = (int) (newImage.Width * (1 + ((double) percentageSize / 100)));
                    int newHeight = (int) (newImage.Height * (1 + ((double) percentageSize / 100)));
                    newImage = ResizeImage(newFileNamePath, newWidth, newHeight);
                    newImage.Save(directory + RESIZED_DIRECTORY + "\\" + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    newImage.Dispose();
                } else {
                    // only move
                    File.Move(newFileNamePath, directory + RESIZED_DIRECTORY + "\\" + newFileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(String path, int width, int height) {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
        destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage)) {
            // process image
            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes()) {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }
        image.Dispose();
        return destImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing that `Image newImage = Image.FromFile(newFileNamePath);` does is put a lock on the file.  It doesn't do anything else.  It is a bug, you'll have to delete that statement.

Comment: `Image newImage = ResizeImage(newFileNamePath, newWidth, newHeight);`

Comment: I added my full code in that if block, please see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original newImage isn't exposed. You are reassigning it and disposing the new imageNew you are receiving from ResizeImage.

Remove the following:

```
Image newImage = Image.FromFile(newFileNamePath);
```

And move your declaration to the next line. This line didn't do anything, since you replace it immediately after and dispose the new replacement, but never the original.

**After edit of OP:**

You should do this:

```
Image newImage = Image.FromFile(newFileNamePath); 
int newWidth = (int) (newImage.Width * (1 + ((double) percentageSize / 100)));
int newHeight = (int) (newImage.Height * (1 + ((double) percentageSize / 100)));
newImage.Dispose();

Image anotherImage = ResizeImage(newFileNamePath, newWidth, newHeight))
anotherImage.Save(directory + RESIZED_DIRECTORY + "\\" + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
anotherImage.Dispose();
```

For explanation purposes I did leave out the use of using. But normally you should do that:

```
using (Image newImage = Image.FromFile(newFileNamePath))
{
    int newWidth = (int) (newImage.Width * (1 + ((double) percentageSize / 100)));
    int newHeight = (int) (newImage.Height * (1 + ((double) percentageSize / 100)));
    using (Image anotherImage = ResizeImage(newFileNamePath, newWidth, newHeight))
        anotherImage.Save(directory + RESIZED_DIRECTORY + "\\" + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: but I need this object, so I can get the initial dimensions of the image

Comment: I edited my code and added the full block, sorry if it was unclear

Comment: as I am kind of new to C# (I come from Java), let me make this clear to myself with all this 'using' statements stuff - so whatever is inside of it, will be immidiatelly disposed of after the compiler leaves its block, right? Is it the same if you use object.Dispose() ?

Comment: You can call Dispose(), but it won't be called if you add more code with early return later of if an exception is thrown. Your original issue wasn't the use of Dispose, but the replacement of resources. If you would have used using you probably wouldn't have made the error.

Comment: Please mark the answer if it is exactly an answer to your question so others that have the same issues with disposing resources can see which answer helped.